# assigning text to a textarea

Tags: jquery

How can I do this in textarea

```
$(this).text() = $(this).text().substring(0, 20);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 20));
```

… but, frankly, this is a horribly inefficient way to achieve this. You are creating jQuery objects and not getting any benefit from them. Plain DOM is better in this case.

```
this.value = this.value.substring(0,20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 20));
```

Comment: I would not advise it if it does. why type more?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to cache the selector in a var if you find yourself doing $(this) or $('#something') multiple times.

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.val( $this.val().substring(0, 20) );
```